# How to track site search in Google Analytics and not count as a page view?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics ([analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages)) to track site searches on my website:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '?q=' + search_term);
```

As you can see I'm using `pageview` as the hit type. My problem is, I don't want a new page view to be recorded each time a user performs a search on my site.

Is it possible to track site search and not have each search count as a separate page view? If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, filtering out these Pageviews will stop Analytics from processing them further down its pipeline, which will not allow you to track Search Terms.

You could create a separate View for your Property, which filters out pages whose URL start with `?q=`.

That would allow you to track the Search Terms entered in your website and retain an overview of your website without the "inflated" Pageviews/Virtual Pageviews of search -- I presume you might be using an Ajax Search on your site?.